# Angular template not updating after object manipulation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object as follows:

```
$scope.allSessions = {
    set: {},
    pending: []
};
```

A method then later fills the `set` property with a bunch of objects like the below

```
"2014-06-07-11-30": {
    blah blah
}
```

This generates a nice list of dates (like the top bit in this image):
[image: List]

I have written a method so that when the X is pressed via an ng-click, the date is removed from the list, and moved into the pending "x session(s) not scheduled" part. The method removes the entry from the `set` property and creates an entry the `pending` array. Here is the method and the template for that:

```
$scope.makeSessionPending = function(session) {
    // Create an entry in pending (only length is required)
    $scope.allSessions.pending.push({
        length: session.length
    });

    // Remove from set sessions
    delete $scope.allSessions.set[session.index];
};

<ul class="sessions">
    <li ng-repeat="session in allSessions.set">
        [[ session.dateString ]]
        <span class="status" ng-class="session.status" ng-if="statusReceived"></span>
        <span class="make-pending" ng-click="makeSessionPending(session)"><i class="icon icon-times"></i></span>
        <span class="remove" ng-click="removeSession(session)"><i class="icon icon-trash-o"></i></span>
    </li>
    <li class="pending" ng-if="allSessions.pending.length">
        <i class="icon icon-ellipsis-h"></i>
        [[ allSessions.pending.length ]] session[[ (allSessions.pending.length == 1) ? '' : 's' ]] not scheduled
    </li>
</ul>
```

My issue is that after the first time a session is made pending the `[[ allSessions.pending.length ]]` is no longer updated. However if I console log at the end of the `makeSessionPending` method it all appear correct, its just the template not reflecting the change in length of the pending array.

Another couple of strange things to note, is that if I inspect that line in the html, it is correct. And when I highlight the line, it updates!?

[image]

Comment: In isolation, your code seems to work fine here: http://plnkr.co/edit/9PEb3pySSWuZyCtwpSii?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the Plunker, I didn't think to test it on there. I notice that in my code, if I remove the delete statement, the pending.length updates fine. It's really bugging me

Comment: Not sure why that would be! All that I can suggest is that you keep comparing to see what differences there are in the Plunker code vs yours.

Comment: After your working Plunker, I decided to remove the CSS relating to the list, it appears to be a position:relative on the li's causing the issue, which is odd!

Answer (score 0):

The issue actually turned out to be a CSS problem, where as soon as I put `position: relative` on the element containing the problem line, it would no longer update.

I ended up having to take the `position: relative` off and work around it